# Check if a string contains a non-alphanumeric character

Tags: c++, string, character, non-alphanumeric

I am trying to write a function which takes a string as an argument and checks if that string **contains only one non-alphanumeric character**, if this is the case then return true, if not, return false.

For example:

```
'Alex's' would return true. 
James..Warner would return false.
```

My current code is below, but I don't feel that its working. As I have a count elsewhere which basically counts the true's. Done using a map which contains the strings. And the value which I am getting for the count is too high for the words that are being input.

```
bool Class3::filter(string word)
    {
        string s = word;
        int len = s.size();

        for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
        {   if(!isalnum(s[i])){
            return true;}
            else{return false;}  
        }
     }
```

Comment: Asking other people to spot errors in your code is not productive.  You should use the debugger to step through your code to find out what's going wrong.

Comment: You want to check if a string contains only one alhpanumeric character *and* `Alex's` would return true? This is contradictory.

Comment: BTW, a comment on your formatting.  While I'm sure you think else{return false;} is completely legible, standard C++ formatting is to put the curly brackets on their own line, or at a minimum add a return character after the open bracket and then give the close bracket it's own line.  THis allows the entire block of code to be indented, aiding in readability.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes you were correct, I have no edited my question to show what I actually meant. Sorry.

Comment: Not related to the question, but `isalnum[s[i]]` is undefined behavior.  The `is...` functions in `<ctype.h>` do not take `char` as an argument.

Comment: Also not related to the question, but rather than make a copy of `word` and store it in `s`, it would be better to pass `word` by reference instead of value: `filter(const string& word)` and then work with `word` directly

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You aren't counting the number of non-alphanumeric characters in your code, do you? you just return true or false on the first character.

Unless you count, you won't find the answer. However, you can stop at the second non-alphanum.

Since you seem to need the exercise in writing code, here's some psuedo-code:

```
int nonalphas = 0;
for ( char in string )
    if ( char is nonalpha )
        nonalphas++;
        if ( nonalphas > 1 )
            break;
return nonalphas == 1;
```

Comment: @KonradRudolph how do you differ "a..b" from "a.b" then?

Comment: This function is only to check that the string is 'valid', I don't think you need to differentiate between invalid strings...  At least, that's how I'm reading a 'filter' as.

Comment: @gustaf Because I misread the question. You’re right, counting is needed. My god, that is one bad task description.

Comment: Ooof, I thought he was comparing against an array of known values -- he knew the array had 500 valid (or invalid, etc) entries and was comparing the results he got against that.

Comment: -1, simply because you downvoted every other answer besides yours and one other solution when you could have kept it neutral. I consider your answer to also be on the same par as inefficient as the other answers in here.

Comment: Ineffective. YOu could return false instead of breaking and then comparing :-)

Comment: @Rapptz I suspect that he's never encountered the term 'premature optimization', and doesn't realize just how incredibly important profiled optimization is -- to the point where a good programmer will be *deliberately* inefficient when attempting to create DRY code that can be easily reused.

Comment: @Rapptz For very large strings with multiple non-alphas, this will break on the first char where the result is known. Hence this will **of course** be more effective. @RonLugge, please explain how this is not more efficient rather than assuming complete incompetence. Show me how profiling can compensate for a `std::count_if` traversing the whole string.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `std::count_if` and then check if the value is greater than 1.

```
int i = std::count_if(str.begin(),str.end(),[](char c){ return !(std::isalnum(c)); });
return i > 1;
```

Comment: -1 for ineffective. Read the comments to the other answers. **EDIT**, sorry, not just ineffective, but incorrect too.

Comment: @gustafr why is it incorrect? Hint: it works with both of OP's provided examples.

Comment: you're right. I'm tired and should go to bed. Still -1 for being inefficient, sorry :/

Answer (score 3):

Your program makes a decision after looking at only a single character; it cannot work like that! When you see that the character is alphanumeric, you return `false` right away, without looking at the remaining characters. To fix, move the `return false` *outside* the loop.

Comment: Actually, I think it's the return true that needs to be moved out...  And better yet might be the use of a regex.

Answer (score 3):

Other's have commented on how badly you've described your issues, and thrown complex template-based code at you that you probably don't understand.  I strongly suggest that you read up on it; templates are powerful, useful, and a great programming technique.  The downside is that you have to learn them first.

Here's a non-template oriented solution:

```
bool class3::filter(string word)
{
    //You aren't mutating word, so don't waste your time
    //(or memory) by copying it.  In fact, I'd (strongly)
    //recommend you utilize a constant pass by reference,
    //because by default that's what you're already doing,
    //so you were taking a copy of a copy.  Waste of memory!

    //Just init a count variable.
    int count=0;

    //Set up your for loop...
    for(int i=0; i<word.size(); i++)
    {
        if(!isalnum(word[i]))
        {
            //If a character doesn't match, increment your counter
            count++;
                            //If you want to, you can return false here if count>1 to improve efficiency -- depends on your end goal.
        }
    }
    //If you want exactly one non-alphanumeric, then return this.
    return count==1;
    //Or if it's a maximum of one non-alphanumeric, then...
    return count<=1;
    //Or you could generalize by returning a count of non alphanumerics -- remember to change the return type!
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I'm not -1:ing this because you at least try hard to be helpful, but it's inefficient to keep looking when count > 1. Please adjust.

Comment: It was meant to be inneficient -- and as simple (to the point of simplicity) as possible.

Comment: @gustafr Also, efficiency isn't everything.  While this is an easy efficiency gain and SHOULD be taken, early optimization is the root of all evil!  Without a better idea of what he's actually trying to accomplish (hence why I had three return options at the end), there's a limit to what kind of optimization SHOULD be done.

Answer (score 3):

As "inefficient" as the next guy.

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <cctype>

// return 'true' if there is one-and-only-one non-alphanumeric character
// in the given std::string parameter. If there are NO non-alphanumeric
// characters, OR more than one, then return 'false'.
bool filter(const std::string& s)
{
    function<bool(char)> is_not_alnum([](char c)->bool{ return !isalnum(c); });
    string::const_iterator first = find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), is_not_alnum);
    return first != s.end() && (find_if(first+1, s.end(), is_not_alnum) == s.end());
}
```

Posted just so I too can get down-voted for "thats not how i'd do it" reasons. I'd rather laugh with the sinners than cry with the saints.

Comment: Your commented about laugh with sinners earned you a +1.  That said...  your code is so incredibly dense I can't make heads or tails of it.  Given that you're doing that deliberately, that's worth a second +1, too bad I can't give it!

Comment: @RonLugge First we call `find_if` to get the first non-alnum char, Failure to find one returns false. If  we found one, we look one more time for one more starting one slot past where we found the first. if another is NOT found, we return true, otherwise we return false. the irony is, it is ultimately very similar to the algorithm the selected answer uses.

Comment: Half the reason I can't make heads or tails of it is that I haven't touched C++ in nearly two years.   I'm much more of a web and iOS dev than I am a C++ dev.  In fact, I never learned most of the STD library because my teachers frowned, heavily, on it's use until my senior year... by which point I more or less stopped using it in favor of other languages.  The other half of my issue, of course, is how compactly you wrote it to condense it all down into 3 lines (something I prefer to avoid in favor of clarity and letting compiler magic do it's thing)

Comment: @RonLugge LOL. yeah, I could have reduced it further, but then all gory fun rolls off the right side of the code listing on my screen. But it works, so at least I have that going for me. =P

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::count_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) in combination with [`std::isalnum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalnum).

```
bool filter(const std::string word)
{
  return std::count_if(word.begin(), word.end(), [](char c){ return !(std::isalnum(c));}) > 1;
}
```

The caveat is that this algorithm checks all the characters in the string. This may or may not be a performance issue.

Comment: -1 for ineffective. You don't always need to count all characters. Also, your answer is a bit of a smack in the face to someone who can't even format code properly. So, +0.5 for that ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `std::count_if` and `lambda`:

```
bool filter(const std::string& s)
{
  if (std::count_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char c){ return !std::isalpha(c); }) == 1)
  {
    cout << s << ": contains one non-alpha charectors" << endl;
    return false;
  }

 cout << s << ": string contains alpha charectors only" << endl;
 return true;      
}
```

Comment: it depends.... if efficiency is required and sting is large